computable sequences
This is either a deep or a silly question. Looking for established results on relationships among integer sequences.
Some sequences in oeis are related to others.
For example, the list of numbers
0, 1, 2, 3,  4,  5,  6,  7, ... A000027
Can be turned into the list (at any k) below by a program that adds up the first k in the list.
0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, ... A000217
Is there always a program that can convert one sequence into another?
Can the simplest program (by some measure of complexity) be found?

I believe the program (if it exists) should not be target-specific, similar to a piecewise function, that would otherwise trivialise the program to $O(n)$.

Broadly speaking, no, for a few reasons, including:

There may be more than one way to transform one sequence into another. For example, if we take your example and let the first sequence be $A_n$ and the second be $B_n$, we can say $B_n = \sum_{k = 0}^n A_k$ or $B_n = \frac{1}{2}A_n(A_n + 1)$ and both give the right answer, so there is not necessarily a single canonical transformation.

We do not necessarily have complete knowledge of the behaviour of any given sequence. In particular, not every sequence may have a known closed form (and in some cases there may be no such closed form using some arbitrarily selected set of allowable operations). What, for example, would be considered an "allowable" transformation of the zero sequence A000004 to the Busy Beaver sequence A028444? It seems like the way to do it is the trivial transformation of A028444(n) = A000004(n) + A028444(n), i.e. "add the $n$th term of the Busy Beaver sequence".


What you're asking about does relate to the OEIS' Superseeker service, which will take a given sequence of numbers and use a variety of methods to compare the given sequence to ones already in the database, including applying over 100 pre-defined transformations.

I did not know about superseeker! That is definitely in the right direction of what I was thinking. Thank you!
